# Hostname is still resolving even after removing entry from zone file of BIND DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, redhat, bind

I have deleted a RHEL server recently . I need to  remove the server hostname record entry from bind dns server so I did remove A record entry from zone file also I removed reverse entry from reverse zone file and I have removed entry from slave server too and after removing entry I have change the serial number and then I ran few command like

> ## rndc reload
>
> ## systemctl restart named.services
>
> ## service nscd restart

Even after all these above steps server is still resolving .
I checked there is no entry in /etc/hosts file

Please suggest me what to do now , I can't reboot it as its  client DNS server I have to go with long process to get approval .

Comment: Did you change the serial value in SOA record?

Comment: yes I did update serial value

Comment: Then you do not need a restart, a simple reload is enough and sometimes even not needed. You are not showing any DNS traces or dig examples or stuff like that, so hard to help you. I believe bind on start shows the zones being loaded and their serial number, make sure they are all correct.

Comment: Appreciate your response . I will add the dig output once I  login . As I have mentioned in question that   after removing the record entry from zone file I have updated the Serial value  then I ran  "rndc reload" command and after that I restarted named service and after that I ran  "service nscd restart" command .  Thanks

Comment: Yes, but again, if you change the serial correctly (you are not even telling in what way you change it, what is old value? new value? the values are irrelevant but can create problems with some typos, etc.), a `rndc reload` should be enough, you shouldn't do the rest. If `rndc reload` is not enough then you have a bigger problem. You can `reload zone` specifically, use `status` and `zonestatus` for information, and maybe you need `freeze` and `thaw`,  no idea, you don't give enough details... not even how your zone is configured in `bind.conf` or equivalent...